# Unexpected jump to begin of question when starting to write comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, android-app

When I use Android Stack Exchange app to read a long question, scroll to near the end of question and am about to reply to some comment, the question viewer suddenly jump back to the beginning of question once the text box for new comment is opened.

I think it is not a reasonable behavior. I may scroll to somewhere I can see the information required for my comment, but the view just changed and I am forced to scroll again just to find the info back. It is a little bit of annoying. The view box should be kept at the same location when the comment text box opens.

I'm using Nexus 9 tablet with Stack Exchange app version 1.0.57.

Comment: What is the question? Is it all questions? Could it be that it hadn't fully loaded (an image or MathJax etc.). I can't reproduce this issue myself.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett All questions. One example is http://stackoverflow.com/q/28751244/718379. Place the tablet in landscape, scroll to the end, touch "add comment" and suddenly it jumps back.

Comment: Ok I've managed to reproduce this issue. Possibly the question I experimented on before was too short. I'm on a Nexus 5.